# Why does Visual Studio run code after my breakpoint during a debug session?

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, cross-browser

I am working on a project in c# that using threading to initialize multiple calls to xcopy to copy user directories from one workstation to a network location.

When I run the program in debug mode, sometimes if I have a break-point BEFORE the program hits the calls to XCopy, and I stop the debugging with the stop button (in VS 2010), the program will then proceed to call the XCopy function, even though I stopped it from reaching the calls in the code.  If I stop inside the foreach loop does the debugger continue to do the other foreach instances?

I know it sounds crazy, but has anyone else ever experienced this, or might you offer some suggestions that would correct this from happening?

A second issue with this is that when I run it from my Win7 machine accessing an XP machine in Firefox, the osInfo is correct, but when my boss runs it on his Win7 machine in IE, it doesn't work.  It makes sense to me that the lines:

```
System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
if (dir_base.Exists && (osInfo.Platform == System.PlatformID.Win32NT)) //XP
```

Should be pulling the system that is running the code, not the network location's operating system type, but the if statement results in true when I run it and false when he does...

Here is my code:

```
    public static void BuildSources_Targets(string Source, string str_Target )
            {
                //XP:
                string str_basePath = Path.Combine(Source, "Documents and Settings");
                var dir_base = new DirectoryInfo(str_basePath);
                System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
                if (dir_base.Exists && (osInfo.Platform == System.PlatformID.Win32NT)) //XP
                {
                    foreach (var dir in dir_base.GetFileSystemInfos())
                    {
                        switch (dir.ToString())
                        {
                            case "administrator":
                            case "Administrator":
                            case "Default User":
                            case "All Users":
                                //Do nothing
                                break;
                            default:
                                string str_dir = dir.ToString();
                                //Handle XP App Data
                                //str_baseAndDirsPath = Path.Combine(dir_base.ToString(), str_dir, Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.ToString());
                                string str_baseAndDirsPath = Path.Combine(dir_base.ToString(), str_dir, "Application Data");
                                DirectoryInfo dir_baseAndDirs = new DirectoryInfo(str_baseAndDirsPath);
                                if (dir_baseAndDirs.Exists)
                                {
                                    string str_Destination = Path.Combine(str_Target, str_dir, "Application Data");
                                    ProcessXcopy(str_baseAndDirsPath, str_Destination);
                                }
                                //Handle XP Documents
                                str_baseAndDirsPath = Path.Combine(dir_base.ToString(), str_dir, "My Documents");
                                dir_baseAndDirs = new DirectoryInfo(str_baseAndDirsPath);
                                if (dir_baseAndDirs.Exists)
                                {
                                    string str_Destination = Path.Combine(str_Target, str_dir, str_dir + " Documents");
                                    ProcessXcopy(str_baseAndDirsPath, str_Destination);
                                }
                                break;
                        } //end of switch
                    }  //end of foreach
                } //end of dir_base.exists
//it continues from here...but that's enough to illustrate my problem...
```

Comment: That is unexpected. Breakpoints may fail if the compiled program mismatches your source code, but usually that's clear from the UI. Could it be you are seeing the first xcopy showing up, and you are mistaking it for the second? Your program might not do a blocking wait on xcopy.

Comment: I stop the program execution before ANY of the Xcopys can occur.  But, they still seem to trigger.  I know because the console windows pop up over the code(2 monitors), the copies that DO work show up in the Test Destination location.  The ProcessXcopy calls are well after the breakpoints, usually set around the other issue.

Comment: I stopped the execution before the code cursor gets to the switch statement, and the calls to Xcopy (inside ProcessXcopy function) is at the bottom of the switch (as you can see above).

Comment: And what is `osInfo.Platform` on your boss's machine? Is it possible that `dir_base` doesn't exist? I find it pretty unlikely that Windows 7 would report something other than `Win32NT` for platform ID.

Comment: When we ran the program we pointed to the same virtual XP machine for the tests.  His resulted in (false) at that if statement while mine resulted in (true).  When he ran it pointed to his personal machine, (which is Win7), it resulted in (false) as Win7 doesn't have a "Documents and Settings" directory.

Comment: My point is that the problem is probably with `dir_base` rather than with `osInfo.Platform`. If his machine can't see that virtual XP machine, it could be because sharing isn't turned on. Can you view it from the command line? (i.e. `dir \\machine\directory`)

Comment: I can view it with dir.  But, I have to believe that he could too, as my machine was cloned from his.